# Comparing amount of characters in strings in Python

Tags: python

In a word guessing game, how would I be able to note the difference in amount of characters between guesses and the answer?  eg. word to be guessed is 'answer', guess is 'answering', noted as a difference of 3 characters.  I'm just struggling to understand string to int conversion, if that's the path I should be taking...

Comment: Simply use `abs(len(word) - len(guess))`?

Comment: Do you just want to compare length, or do you want to compare the contents of the strings, too? What is the expected difference of "cat" and "dog"? What about "bat" and "tab"? What about "bet" and "abet"?

Comment: compare the contents, yeah... so in your examples, cat & dog = difference of 3, bat & tab = difference of 2, bet & abet = difference of 1.

Comment: @PdTame Take a look at [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html).

Comment: How about the difference between "ABCXYZ" and "ABCOXYZ"? The alogorithm that produces `4` is a lot easier to write than the one that produces `1`.

Comment: @Kevin Maybe that will be `1`.

Answer (score 2):

So what about simply use [`difflib.ndiff()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff) method like this? I think this function can works fine:

```
import difflib
def check_diff(a, b):
    diff = [i[0] for i in difflib.ndiff(a, b) if i[0] != ' ']
    nums = abs(diff.count('+') - diff.count('-'))
    return (nums if nums != 0 else diff.count('+'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import difflib
>>> def check_diff(a, b):
...     diff = [i[0] for i in difflib.ndiff(a, b) if i[0] != ' ']
...     nums = abs(diff.count('+') - diff.count('-'))
...     return (nums if nums != 0 else diff.count('+')) 
... 
>>> 
>>> check_diff('cat', 'dog')
3
>>> check_diff('bat', 'tab')
2
>>> check_diff('bet', 'abet')
1
>>> check_diff('ABCXYZ', 'ABCOXYZ')
1
>>> check_diff('ABCXYZ', 'ABXYZ')
1
>>> check_diff('ABCXYZ', 'ABXZ')
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @KevinGuan said in comment you can use diiflib.
here is an example function:

```
def diff(a ,b):
    sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)
    match_size = sm.find_longest_match(0, len(a), 0, len(b)).size
    return max(len(a), len(b)) - match_size

print diff('cat', 'dog')
print diff('bat', 'tab')
print diff('answer', 'answering')
print diff('bet', 'abet')
```

output is:

```
3
2
3
1
```